# Bamboo artifact sharing - what is default branch

Tags: bamboo, artifact

I have a build ***plan B*** which downloads an artifact from ***plan A***.

From which branch on ***plan A*** will the artifact's be downloaded. Is it *master* or the same branch as the one being build on ***plan B***? With other words, will the branch be the same accros build plan's during artifact sharing?

Br
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both plans have the same branches configured, Plan B will use the artifacts from the same branch of Plan A that Plan B is currently building.

Comment: What about deployment plans?

Comment: Is there a way to alter this behaviour? In my setup I would always want to download an atrifact from master of Plan A even if there is a branch of the same name as in Plan B.

Comment: @preeze I am afraid it's not possible.

Comment: @Carl G Edit your deployment project and choose `Use a custom plan branch`.

Comment: And what happens, if the same plan does not exist in Plan A?

Answer (score 0):

And if the build plan branch does not exist in plan A, plan B will try to download artifact from the main branch in plan A.

Main branch is configured in 'Plan Configuration > Repositories' tab.